# In Visual Studio 2013, struct member `distance` is in blue, instead of black, why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, std

I write this struct definition in a `.h` file, in my C++ projects:

```cpp
typedef struct {
    int obj_id;
    int obj_class;
    float distance;
} MSE_IN_OBJ;
```

Opened in Visual Studio 2013(update 5), the member `distance` is in blue color, while other member variables are in black.

[image: VS2013]

Why is `distance` in blue instead of the other color?

Also tried VS2017/VS2019, `distance` is not in blue color. Weird.

[image: In VS2017/2019]

I've searched in Google and notice there is a function `std::distance`. However I just put my struct in the first line of my `.h` file.

Update:
I've also tried in my vim editor, it gives:

[image]

And I figured out in my vim config, this plugin https://github.com/octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight makes `distance` a different color (naming it is a function in the standard library )

Comment: Perhaps adding to your compiler's confusion is because this is a C-style structure in C++ code? That this is not really C++? C and C++ are two different languages, and your compiler may be under the impression that you're writing C++ code, and not C?

Comment: do you have `using nammespace std` in your code somewhere?

Comment: The syntax highlighter (part of IntelliSense?) isn't driven by a real C++ compiler (at least, in VS2013). Thus, it may sometimes make wrong output. And I strongly agree that it has been improved much with newer versions of VS. I wouldn't care too much about this as long as there are no (real) compiler complaints...

Comment: @AlanBirtles I don't have `using namespace std`. I've tested in vs2013, put that struct in a `.c` file, it still in blue.

Comment: @Scheff The motivation that I ask this "weird color" question, is that when using that struct as std::vector template type, when running on device (arm-linux-gnueabihf) will get different result that on Visual Studio.

Comment: _when running on device (arm-linux-gnueabihf) will get different result that on Visual Studio_ ??? It is not blue anymore? Are you asking why IntelliSense doesn't work always reliable on VS2013? This is neither new nor surprising... ([Google "Don't trust IntelliSense"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Don%27t+trust+IntelliSense%22) to see what I mean.)

Comment: It seems that intellisense treats `distance` as the keyword `std::distance`. This problem no longer appears on VS2017 and VS2019. In fact, intellisense has been continuously improving. I suggest that you could submit this question to [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).